# Cannot SSH to server from home connection

Tags: macos, ssh

Last night I was connected to my school's server through ssh and after being idle got disconnected. I haven't been able to log back in since, and since I need to submit a file through the server for an assignment I tried to connect with my phone. So I got that to work, and then logged in with my computer with my phone's internet connection through hotspot. This worked and I was able to successfully log in. What could be causing me to not be able to log in from my home network?

Some things that I have done to resolve this (to no avail) are deleting the ~/.ssh directory and starting anew, and also using this command `ssh -c aes256-ctr` to shorten the ciphers (no idea what that is) from [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151860/ssh-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer) on Unix stackxchange. I am running OSX Yosemite 10.10.5. Thanks for all the help in advance.

EDIT: The error I get right after attempting to connect is `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`.

Comment: What is the error you get? *timed out*?

Comment: @AniMenon sorry, the error I get right after attempting to connect is `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***The question is a little broad to answer ***

But here are possibilities :

Your error maybe explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151860/ssh-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer).

Other possibilities:

1. Your connection has frozen as the session is suspended being idle. To avoid this : [application-level keep-alives for SSH](https://askubuntu.com/a/29967)
2. [Check](https://serverfault.com/questions/445045/ssh-connection-error-ssh-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-pe)

[Refer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29942/how-can-i-break-out-of-ssh-when-it-locks)